# Get Public tweets Twitter API 1.1

Tags: android, twitter

I am first time on Twitter API's

I was going through 
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

I need to get the public tweets from https://twitter.com/twitterapi

The api 1.1 link says-

Authentication - Required

And I found something like - AuthTool

I couldn't connect all these things, as there is no beginner tutorial available.

My Basic doubts
 - Does Authentication Required means - the end user using my app should have a twitter account to get these tweets? ( I am planing for a mobile app ( android), to show some celebrity's public tweets )

- Where can I find some basic tutorials to begin with?
- Do I need some tokens to pass with the request? How to get those?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just had a chance to work on a similar issue. Let me help with your questions first.

> Does Authentication Required means - the end user using my app should
>   have a twitter account to get these tweets?

**No.** The end user need not have to sign into his Twitter account to see public feeds. But, you will have to use the consumer key and secret key for the app that you have created in the Twitter developers website.

> Do I need some tokens to pass with the request? How to get those?

As I have explained to the previous question, you need to make use of consumer key, consumer secret, access token and access secret.

Here is a little example which I worked on to get public feeds. The below sample will fetch latest 20 public feeds of the user.

> Before that you need to import the latest twitter library into your project which is twitter4j 3.0.3 as of now.

And then add the below given code to your project and should be done.

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                .setOAuthConsumerKey("B***************Q")
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(
                        "l*********************************o")
                .setOAuthAccessToken(
                        "1*******************************X")
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(
                        "1***************************c");
        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
        try {
            List<Status> statuses;
            String user;
            user = "replace with the user name of your choice";
            statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(user);
            Log.i("Status Count", statuses.size() + " Feeds");
            for (int i = 0; i < statuses.size(); i++) {
                Status status = statuses.get(i);
                Log.i("Tweet Count " + (i + 1), status.getText() + "\n\n");
            }
        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: How do you get Access Token and Access Token Secret if you're not authenticated?

Comment: go to the twitter dev site where you created your twitter app. It will have its own access token and access secret. You should use it for authentication.

Comment: To clarify this answer further, if you go to the apps.twitter.com page where you created the app, you can explicitly create a user access token and secret for your account with the app on that page.